# What is +=symbol called in Adding multiple delegates to a delegate object?

Tags: asp.net, delegates

```
public delegate void ExecuteCallback();
```

class Executioner
{
    private ExecuteCallback _doExecute;

```
public void AddMultiple()
{
    // Add a delegate to MethodA
    // This will work even if _doExecute is currently null
    _doExecute += new Execute( MethodA );

    // Add a delegate to MethodB also
    _doExecute += new Execute( MethodB );

    // Add a delegate to MethodC also
    _doExecute += new Execute( MethodC );
}

public void MethodA()
{
    //...
}

public void MethodB()
{
    //...
}

public void MethodC()
{
    //...
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+=` is usually called the "addition assignment operator" but in the context of delegates...

> The += operator is also used to
>   specify a method that will be called
>   in response to an event; such methods
>   are called event handlers. The use of
>   the += operator in this context is
>   referred to as subscribing to an
>   event.

Taken from MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx).

[How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)

Comment: Note that the handling of events and delegates is quite different.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a shorthand provided by C# for calling [`Delegate.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.combine.aspx). It also works for events, where it calls the subscription part of the event (the `add {}` block in a C# event declaration, for example).

I don't believe there's a particular name for combination - it's just the binary + and += operators, from sections 7.8.4 and 7.17.2 of the C# spec, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably refer to that as 'registering' the event handler with the delegate / event. Depending on context.